# Hibernate Extra Lazy oneToMany association, using contains() method comparing by other field than id?

Tags: java, hibernate

As you know, you can declare a OneToMany association with ExtraLazy semantics, in Hibernate, and that means that size(), contains() and others might become smarter. It will run specific SQL statement and will not initialize the entire collection. Great feature for large collection.

The thing is that looks like the contains() method, only compares by Id (primary key). Suppose this example:

```
    class Department {
        ........
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
        @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
        private Collection<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        .........
        public void addEmployee(Employee e) {
           if (!this.employees.contains(e)) {
              employees.add(e);
              e.setDepartment(this);
           }
        }
    }
```

The code above is a Department class with a OneToMany association to Employee (another Entity), using ExtraLazy. And on the addEmployee() method, I use the method contains() of the PersistentBag in this case.

When I see the SQL statements generated by Hibernate, I see that it issued a SQL comparing by ID of the Employee. 
What if I want to check if the Employee exists by name, due to I don't want to have Employee with the same name in the Deparment? or other field of the Employee? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Worth to mention that the PersistentBag#contains(), if extraLazy is used, does not call the method Employee#equals, due to the collection is not initialized.

Comment: You can use HQL for that purpose.

Comment: How? I want to avoid destroying my domain model, is that possible withtout that?

Comment: [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html).

Comment: Thanks. I know HQL, but that will make me change the Employee class in a way that I don't want.

Comment: `select distinct 1 from Employee e where e.name = :name and e.department.id = :departmentId`. No model class changes needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107901/discussion-between-epm-and-dragan-bozanovic).